# D3 Charts issue while plotting line charts with weekday in the x-axis

Tags: d3.js

I have weekdays in the x-axis and numbers from (EC) in the y-axis, When I try to plot a line chart, the line is plotted along the yaxis and is not taking the weekday values and also not displaying the weekday in the x-axis.

I am stuck here and can you please help me with this. I have my code in the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/BuNB5/

```
var data=[{"Day":"Sunday","EC":1},{"Day":"Monday","EC":4424},{"Day":"Tuesday","EC":3408},{"Day":"Wednesday","EC":3137},{"Day":"Thursday","EC":2239},{"Day":"Friday","EC":3090},{"Day":"Saturday","EC":209}];

// set up a drawing context
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 100
};
var width = 540 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 330 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// d3 init
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var format = d3.time.format("%A");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
        .ticks(6)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%A"));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(10);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
);
var dateFn = function(d) { return format.parse(d.Day) };

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(dateFn(d)); })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.EC);});


    // Scale the range of the data
    //x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.Day; })));
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn))
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.EC;
    })]);

    svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the black dots
    svg.selectAll("dot")                                    
        .data(data)                                         
        .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
        //.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Day); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.EC); }) 

    // Add the axes
    svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
```

Looking forward for a solution to this issue and really appreciate your help to find what I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm, looks like a bug to me. You could file [an issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues?state=open).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have created a issue and hoping to hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `d3.time.format().parse()` to convert days of the week into dates. That's not really possible, because "Monday" could be any date that falls on a "Monday".

So, instead of calling `format.parse(d.Day)`, you need another means of turning a day of the week into a Date.

You can start by establishing a Sunday Date that would serve as the first day of the week and would appear left-most in your graph. It can be any Sunday at any point in the past or future, but let's use yesterday's Sunday. That means:

```
var aSunday = Number( new Date(2014, 0, 5) ) // Sunday, Jan 5th, 2014
```

Now, for every day of the week, you need to calculate an offset between that day and the Sunday before it. First, you need an array of all the days of the week, starting with Sunday:

```
var days=['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
          'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

This way, `days.indexOf(d.Day)` would return the index of that day relative to Sunday. For example, `"Tuesday"` would have an index of 2, which is 2 days after Sunday. If you multiply that by the number of milliseconds per 24 hour day, you get the amount of milliseconds you need to add to `aSunday` in order to get a Date object representing that following Tuesday:

```
var msPerDay = 86400000 // 24 hours in milliseconds
var dateFn = function(d) { return aSunday + msPerDay * days.indexOf(d.Day); };
```

[Here's how it works with you jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/BuNB5/2/).

**That being said, it's probably most appropriate to ditch `d3.time.scale()` and use `d3.scale.ordinal()` instead. [Check this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/BuNB5/4/), which uses ordinal scale and doesn't know anything about Dates or time.**

Also, come to think of it, the date-based approach may not play well with daylight savings. I strongly recommend the ordinal scale -based approach.